# How to Connect local instance of oracle sql developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am absolute beginner to oracle and thought of getting started with installing Oracle Sql developer.
Basically i downloaded the zip package and unzipped to program files and opened sqldeveloper.exe.
Then I chose New connection and then filled the connection name,username,password and others but when I test the connection I get the following error.

> Status : Failure-Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

I'm looking to connect to local database for practicing queries.
How do I fix this, is there something else I should install?

Comment: What value have you given as hostname?

Comment: localhost is the hostname and Port is 1521,Which are the default ones.

Comment: There are many things that could be causing this. Here is a link to the latest documentation on setting up SQL Developer. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39885_01/appdev.40/e38414/intro.htm#RPTUG10000

Comment: Did you install a database? SQL Developer doesn't come with an Oracle database.

Comment: No how do I install it?

Comment: Here is a link to the downloads page: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html

Comment: Thank you i'm downloading it

Answer (score 4):

Before downloading the Sql Developer, Download the Latest version of Oracle Database from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html)

**1)** Now run the Downloaded Oracle database and during installation, it will prompt to create a password for User named 'SYSTEM' .

In my case i have created the password as 'oracle'.

So my credentials for Oracle Database are

**User Name:** SYSTEM

**Password :** oracle

2) Now download the SQL Developer and extract it to a local folder.Once Extracted, click the sql developer application file --> Connections Tab --> New Connection (+ icon)-->

**Connection Name:** TestConn (give some random name)

**Username:** SYSTEM

**Password:** oracle (the password i have given during installation of oracle database)

Leave all the other default fields as they are .(see the screenshot below).

Click on test for testing the connection.

[image: Database Connection]

***References:-***

https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/12/i-have-oracle-sql-developer-installed-now-what/